# Issue building opencv using FetchContent cmake command

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, fetchcontent

I really need your help because I really don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Using the very simple attached CMakeLists.txt, I got the following error (a lot of times):

```
CMake Error in build/_deps/opencv-src/modules/core/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "opencv_core" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path:

    "/home/myuser/tmp/build"

  which is prefixed in the build directory.
```

Can you help me fix it ?

Thank you for the help.

The CMakeLists.txt I am using:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(TEST_PROJECT)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL "3.24.0")
        cmake_policy(SET CMP0135 NEW)
endif ()

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        opencv
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
        GIT_TAG 4.6.0
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(opencv)
set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

Comment: I'm only guessing, but the line `set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})` might be your problem.

Comment: you might find conan or vcpkg easier to use than `FetchContent`

Comment: Tried the same on a Windows system - with no success either.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same on a Windows system - with no success either.

In the end, I installed OpenCV outside of the build and source tree. Then used only find_package in the CMakeList.txt.

I had problems passing varibales to the OpenCV build when using FetchContent too. E.g. for using TBB or CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

As @sweenish guessed, the problem was the `OpenCV_DIR` variable definition. So I remove this line and add the `OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE` in the `FetchContent_Declare` call. And now it works fine on both systems, Linux and Windows.

My CMakeLists.txt now looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(TEST_PROJECT)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL "3.24.0")
        cmake_policy(SET CMP0135 NEW)
endif ()

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        opencv
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
        GIT_TAG 4.6.0
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
        OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(opencv)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Note, that option `OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE` has been introduced only in CMake 3.24 (see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_declare)), so you are better to update VERSION specified in `cmake_minimum_required` command.